How to do proto DataStore-to proto DataStore migrations using Dagger Hilt
I have seen this blog https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-data-migration-fdca806eb1aa, but it is not quite detail. It does not show how to do data migration of proto datastore plus how you do it using Dagger Hilt.
This is what I have done so far.
I have a AppSettings (like AppPreferences)
@Serializable
data class AppSettings(
    val prepareSeconds: Long = 10L,
    val workSeconds: Long = 90L,
    val restSeconds: Long = 30L,
    val totalSets: Int = 3
) {
    companion object {
        fun getDefaultInstance() = AppSettings()
    }
}

Serialiser (I don't use .proto file, I have a Preferences Data Class & deserialize and serialize it)
object AppSettingsSerializer : Serializer<AppSettings> {

    override val defaultValue: AppSettings
        get() = AppSettings()

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): AppSettings {
        return try {
            Json.decodeFromString(
                deserializer = AppSettings.serializer(),
                string = input.readBytes().decodeToString()
            )
        } catch (e: SerializationException) {
            throw CorruptionException("Unable to read AppSettingsPrefs", e)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
    override suspend fun writeTo(t: AppSettings, output: OutputStream) {
        output.write(
            Json.encodeToString(
                serializer = AppSettings.serializer(),
                value = t
            ).encodeToByteArray()
        )
    }
}

Dagger Hilt Module finally
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppSettingsDataStore(
        @ApplicationContext appContext: Context,
        coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    ): DataStore<AppSettings> {
        return DataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = AppSettingsSerializer,
            corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler {
                AppSettings.getDefaultInstance()
            },
            scope = coroutineScope,
            produceFile = {
                appContext.dataStoreFile(DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME)
            },
            migrations = listOf(object : DataMigration<AppSettings> {

                // Specify your condition for whether the migration should happen
                override suspend fun shouldMigrate(currentData: AppSettings) = true

                // Instruction on how exactly the old data is transformed into new data
                // I DO NOT THINK THIS IS RIGHT WAY TO DO IT, HOW SHOULD IT BE DONE??
                override suspend fun migrate(currentData: AppSettings): AppSettings =
                       AppSettings(
                        prepareSeconds = currentData.prepareSeconds,
                        workSeconds = currentData.workSeconds,
                        restSeconds = currentData.restSeconds,
                        totalSets = currentData.totalSets,
                    )
           

                // Once the migration is over, clean up the old storage
                override suspend fun cleanUp() = Unit
            })
        )
    }

When I update AppSettings (Preferences) with new field/update existing field name/ delete some field. Then DataStore not do migration but re-intialise with default value.
What I am doing wrong. Can anyone give me any resources/blog or code on how to do data migration of proto datastore using Dagger Hilt.

This happens most probably only when you remove some field from the DataStore. Because of this, your deserializer throws CorruptionException and creates new AppSettings instance in corruptionHandler. To resolve, you need to instruct json to ignore unknown keys (no more used in your AppSettings).
val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true } // Ignore unknown keys to prevent errors when removing some parameters
            return json.decodeFromString(
                UserPreferences.serializer(), input.readBytes().decodeToString()
            )

